# VS2010 extension resources?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Is there any way to find out how much resources each VS2010 extension is eating up?

VS is using ~25% CPU and 1GB of RAM with only a few files being edited, and nothing else. I am pretty sure this is not related to VS but to some plugin gone haywire.

Comment: Actually that sounds about right but it really depends on the solution size as well and a bunch of other factors. Try disabling all of the extensions and seeing how much lower it goes and add one by one until you find the culprit

Comment: Don't have vs2010 on my current laptop, but have you tried disabling them one by one? Not ideal, but I don't know of a way to see what resources they are taking up to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

disabled one by one to find out which one was causing the problem... "JS Enhancements"